# plupload to s3, no progress bar

Tags: flash, amazon-s3, plupload

I'm using http://www.plupload.com/, uploading straight to s3, 
using a similar example to

https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/s3.php

It works fine, however using flash a runtime, I get no progress indication.
For a large file, it sits at 0% for a minute or so then jumps to 100%.

Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not an issue, or at least not of the Plupload. I guess you are either using image resize on client-side, or are forcing Plupload into URLStream mode. URLStream doesn't have support for progress indication (Flash limitation). If neither is the case, check s3 example from the latest Plupload release (1.4.2). It has example of how to get progress with Flash runtime and a better explanation of the problem.